# IOS FacebookSDK FBLoginView

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am developing an IOS application. And use IOS FacebookSDK 3.10. I use FBLoginView for facebook login. When I opened my own login screen, sometimes automatically doing login, If user filled facebook login info in iPhone settings. I'm doing automatic logout When user openned login screen. Below code.

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

## Question 1

How can I prevent it.

## Question 2

Can I handle When user FBLoginView clicked. I want to disable to FBLoginView If user clicked. Because user can multiple times until login complated